# Selecting all data if the string is empty in SQL IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure for the Filters of products in my website which goes like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_product_get_by_filters]
    (@brand_names nvarchar(max),
     @type nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT     
        tbl_product.product_code, 
        tbl_product.brand_name, 
        tbl_product.subcategory_code, 
        tbl_product.product_name, 
        tbl_product.product_photo_1,
        tbl_product.filter_code, 
        (select filter_name from tbl_filter where filter_code =  tbl_product.filter_code )as filter_name,
        (select AVG(CAST(rating AS DECIMAL(10,2))) from tbl_review where product_code = tbl_product.product_code) as Rating,
        (select TOP 1 sub_product_price from tbl_sub_product where product_code = tbl_product.product_code) as product_price,
        (select TOP 1 size from tbl_sub_product where product_code = tbl_product.product_code) as size,
        (select TOP 1 sub_product_code from tbl_sub_product where  product_code = tbl_product.product_code) as sub_product_code
    FROM  
        tbl_product 
    WHERE 
        tbl_product.brand_name IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring(@brand_names)) 
        AND tbl_product.filter_code IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring(@type)) 
END
```

`@brand_names` here is a string of the name of brands separated by comma for example

```
Apple,Samsung,Nokia
```

and `@type` is the filter of the products which is like

```
 'Watch,Mobile,Tablet'
```

The `dbo.splitstring` function separates each value from the concatenated string and return the list as a table. So the problem when a User select both Brand Name and Type the query returns the values but if a user select only Brand Name or Type the query doesn't return anything. I want to make the query to return the products if the user select both Brand Name and Type or don't select any of them (You know like filters in every e-commerce website). If the user doesn't select any filter I am passing an empty string in variables like if user doesn't select any brand then @brand_names will be `@brand_names = ''`.

For example if a user select Brand Name Apple the query must return all the products related to this brand. And again if the user select the Type watch then the query must return the Watches from brand Apple. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thank you for the Help.

Comment: dbo.splitstring => Is this your custom function? Maybe use STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator ) .
Also, CSV as parameter is not the best idea. What is calling this SP? C# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of "optional parameter" query, an `option recompile` at the end can improve performance by quite a lot.

If an "unselected" parameter is an empty string, then you can do:

```
WHERE 
   (@brand_names = '' or tbl_product.brand_name IN (SELECT * from dbo.splitstring(@brand_names)))
   and (@type = '' or tbl_product.filter_code IN (SELECT * from dbo.splitstring(@type)))
option (recompile)
```

The `option (recompile)` tells SQL to build a new plan for this statement every time the procedure runs. So, for example, if you pass an empty string for `@brand_names`, the engine doesn't even need to evaluate the `or tbl_product.brand_name in ...` part of that predicate.  If you don't do this, then SQL will - as always - build a plan for the first execution, and then reuse that plan on subsequent executions. That's not great when different parameter values can make such a big difference to the result.

Comment: Dude, you are awesome. Thanks a lot!. Can I ask what does *option recompile* did?

Comment: @ygssoni I have added a bit more explanation to the answer.

Comment: recompile forces the server to interpret the code once again, discarding any existing plan ... the new optimizer-run will generate a completely different execution plan resulting in increased performance (in this scenario)